# How to send message/data with Spring Cloud Streams Supplier?

Tags: java, spring, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to send message on `kafka` when there is an insertion in a particular table `Record`.
I consider that this part of the application will be considered a `Supplier`/`Producer`.

I have following code.

```
@Bean
public Supplier<RecordAlteredEvent> affectedRecordEventEmitter() {
    return (/*how do I pass the data?*/) -> {
            
        log.info("SENDING_MESSAGE TO RECORD_EVENT_TOPIC");
        return new RecordAlteredEvent();
    };
}
```

I actually want to send the data. So, I am looking for something more like following:

```
@Bean
public Function<RecordAlteredEvent, RecordAlteredEvent> alteredRecordEventEmitter() {
    return (RecordAlteredEvent recordAlteredEvent) -> {
        log.info(SENDING_MESSAGE, VDP_USERS_EVENT_TOPIC, recordAlteredEvent.toString());
        return recordAlteredEvent;
    };
    }
```

Is this possible? How do I configure that ? So, for example if

1. I declare a 'Supplier' then how do I pass data to it ?
2. And if I declare a 'Function' it seems that the input will be received from the `topic` and forwarded. And I am not receiving the data from `topic`. I am receiving data from `REST API`/`DB`.

I am not sure if the following can somehow help: But with a basic try I could not succeed. hence, an example will help a lot.

```
@Autowired
private StreamBridge streamBridge;

// Can following work somehow in-side a function that is, for example, in spring-boot-service  
streamBridge.send("myDestination", body);
```

For reference:

1. https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring_cloud_function
2. https://tanzu.vmware.com/developer/guides/scs-gs/

   - Section : Generating Loan Applications
3. [How can create a producer using Spring Cloud Kafka Stream 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65835964/how-can-create-a-producer-using-spring-cloud-kafka-stream-3-1)

Comment: You don't "send" data to a supplier; it supplies data. The `StreamBridge` is the correct approach for sending arbitrary data to bindings. https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources

Answer (score 2):

Following worked

declare field

```
  private final StreamBridge streamBridge;
```

Declared functions

```
  public void delegateRecordsEventSupplier(@NotNull final RecordsEvent alteredRecordsEvent) {
    streamBridge.send("affectedRecordsEvent-out-0", alteredRecordsEvent);
  }
```

These functions when called will place the message on the `topic`

Comment: Noticed that when using _streamBridge_ the binding can be called without suffix and index, so it can be simply `affectedRecordsEvent`.